# PHP/MySQL Echoing in wrong order & also echoing column header instead of row value of that column?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

sorry if the title is worded a bit strange and awkward.

I have a system which creates a table through AJAX/PHP/MySQL, but for some reason I'm having a couple problems.

To start with, here's the PHP echoing the results in a table

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) {
$quote=$quote."<h3>Hard Enamel</h3>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $quote=$quote."<p>Size: ".$row["type"]."<br />Extras: ".$HEextras."</p>
    <table border='1' width='300' cellpadding='3'>
    <tr>
    <th width='100'>Quantity</th>
    <th width='100'>Unit Cost</th>
    <th width='100'>Setup</th>
    </tr>";


    if($row["100"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>100</td><td>".cost($row["100"])."</td><td>".setup($row["setup"])."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["250"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>250</td><td>".cost($row["250"])."</td><td>".setup($row["setup"])."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["500"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>500</td><td>".cost($row["500"])."</td><td>".setup($row["setup"])."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["1000"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>1,000</td><td>".cost($row["1000"])."</td><td>".setup($row["setup"])."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["2500"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>2,500</td><td>".cost($row["2500"])."</td><td>".setup($row["setup"])."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["5000"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>5,000</td><td>".cost($row["5000"])."</td><td>".setup(0)."</td></tr>";
    }
    if($row["10000"]) {
        $quote=$quote."<tr><td>10,000</td><td>".cost($row["10000"])."</td><td>".setup(0)."</td></tr>";
    }
    $quote=$quote."<br />";
}

echo $quote;
}
```

While testing I have the SQL returning 2 rows of data with columns `type`, `100`, `250` & `setup`, with the column `type` values being 12mm and 16mm. These return fine and so does the setup values, but the values for columns `100` & `250` return the column headers. Also tried without the cost() function but doesnt change anything.

Also, it reads in the wrong order, which I have no clue why! Returned result below.

```
Hard Enamel

Size: 12mm
Extras: extrastring


Size: 16mm
Extras: extrastring

Quantity    Unit Cost   Setup
100 100 40
250 250 40

Quantity    Unit Cost   Setup
100 100 40
250 250 40
```

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Can you add the SQL string you use? I'm guessing you might be missing the backticks on the 100 & 250 column names, so SQL is treating them as literals.

Comment: @danielpsc Thanks, properly escaping with backticks worked (silly mistake, Im a beginner) - Any idea on the strange order of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to take a wild guess, it may have something to do with using `mysql_fetch_array()` along with having numeric column names. The `mysql_fetch_array()` function will, by default, return an array with both positional and labeled indices. Something may be getting confused in there.

I would try:

- using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`
- changing the column names in your database to be non-numeric (this is a good idea anyway)
- making sure that your query is properly escaping the column names if they do remain numeric

If none of those have any effect, it would be helpful to see the exact data contained in the database and the query being used to fetch it, as those could also be potential problems.

Comment: Thanks, changing the column name and properly escaping with backticks worked - Any idea on the strange order of things?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a closing `</table>` at the end of your loop, which could be causing it to display oddly.

Comment: I think @futureal is right - your `$quote=$quote."<br />";` problably just needs to be `$quote=$quote."</table>";` else you're starting a new table before you close the first one.

Comment: @futureal ah jeez, its always the simplest things i miss haha - thanks alot guys!